# How to store an Object, an int and a index at the same time? (Android)

Tags: object, indexing, int

I have a situation where I want to store a `bitmap(Object)`, int `value(speed of bitmap)` and another index value to access these other 2. Any ideas? Was thinking in using `HashMap` however, hashmaps only deals with the `Object` and `Index`, but need another integer value that will be associated with that specific `Object`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need a dedicated type for the bitmap and the speed. If the index is used to retrieve the other two values, pack them into a type:

```
class FlyingBitmap{
        private Bitmap bitmap;
        private double speed;
        ...
    }
```

and use a `HashMap`

```
Map<Integer, FlyingBitmap> map = new HashMap<Integer, FlyingBitmap>();
```

Comment: thx @kostja, why I didn't think of creating my own class! :D
thx